# Questions regarding the Sigma notation

Tags: calculus, integration, riemann-sum

I have a problem about estimating the area under a curve $f(x)$ with right endpoints using $4$ rectangles.

I know how to work through the mechanics of the problem but I am really trying to understand the underlying fundamentals better.

---

If I use Sigma notation to write this problem out, my confusion lies in how the variable $i$ relates to $n$.
$$
\sum_{i}^n f(x)
$$
on simple problems usually $i = 1$ which leads me to believe that $i$ iterates through the sum of:
$$
x_{1} + x_{2} + x_{3}...x_{n}
$$

However, when I have a problem like:
$$
f(x) = \cos(x)
$$
which asks me to estimate its area with $4$ rectangles using right endpoints from 
$
[0,\pi/2].
$

I ultimately get lost in how to properly display this using sigma notation since in this case:
$
n=4,
$
which leads me to believe I should represent this as such:
$$
\sum_{i}^{n=4} \cos(x)
$$

BUT, that doesn't make sense according to a description of the sigma notation I read in my textbook which says:
$$
\sum_{i = m}^n f(x_{i})\Delta x
$$

which, according to the definition in my text, tells us to end with:
$$
i=n
$$

and to start with:
$$
i=m
$$

which means that if I have to find an Area under the curve between:
$$
[0,\pi/2]
$$

then it makes more sense to me, that I should really be thinking about this notation as follows:
$$
\lim_{n\to 4}\sum_{i=0}^{n=\pi/2} cos(x)\Delta x
$$

I say this because the nature of the problem requires that I break up this function to as close to 4 rectangle units as possible depending on whether I need the left or right end point (or midpoint). The iteration starts at i = 0, and terminates at $$\pi/2$$ as needed...

Is this the right way to think about this problem and even more important am I using this notation correctly in the manner that I have described?

Comment: Can you do the problem *without* the $\sum$ notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $\sum_{i=1}^nf(x)$ does not make sense because it literally gives
$$
\sum_{i=1}^nf(x)=n\cdot f(x).
$$

Also, it is completely nonsense (no offense, I'm just talking about the notations here) to write
$$
\lim_{n\to 4}\sum_{i=0}^{n=\pi/2} cos(x)\Delta x.
$$
Because

- $n$ is a positive integer, it does not make sense to write $n=\pi/2$.
- There is *no* limiting process here.
- You should have $x_i$ in $\cos(x)$ instead.

---

> Suppose
>   $
> f(x) = \cos(x)
> $.
>    Estimate its area under $f$ with $4$ rectangles using right endpoints from $
> [0,\pi/2]$.

The sum you are looking for is something like
$$
\sum_{i=1}^4f(x_i)\Delta x.
$$
What you need to figure out is $\Delta x$ and the $x_i$'s. There is *no* limiting process here.

---

Take a careful look at this example:
[image]
[image]

Comment: like i asked in my question I know exactly what to figure out. Like you pointed out, my question is in how i relates to n, exactly. the limit I wrote is based off my understanding of the exact definitions I have read. Can you give a better example as to how i relates to n as your initial sigma notation reiterates the problem I am having and why I asked the question I am asking. I am trying to better understand how to properly use sigma notation. if i have to go from 0 to pi/2 with n=4 how does i relate to n as it is not always 1. i know in this case \Delta x is pi/8...

Comment: When $n=4$, $i$ takes the values $1,2,3,4$. $i$ is *not* a function of $n$. It is a dummy *variable* for the summation sign $\sum$.

Comment: how do i account for the interval being iterated over? [0,pi/2]??? Where do I notate that interval in that sigma notation?

Comment: What you get is $x_1=\pi/8, x_2=\pi/4, x_3=3\pi/8, x_4=\pi/2$.

Comment: Please see the edited answer.

Comment: i know all that and i get how to perform the calculation. the confusion is coming from the books definition at i starting with i = m and ending with i = n... all good...

Comment: Then let $m=1$ and $n=4$. What is wrong with that? Perhaps you could provide your textbook information in your post so that one can see what is really your question.

Comment: i wrote it down with the starting at i = m data in the question, maybe im just over thinking it. thank you for your help

Comment: thanks, i see where that limit issue doesnt make sense. i just have to take the interval in which its on to find the DeltaX and thats it. the sigma notation just tells me to sum the function at n rectangles and i just have to be satisfied with that. its one of those things you just have to accept about notation like this, there is nothing more to it than what it is. I think alot of people like me create math obstacles for ourselves by over thinking notation like this thinking that there is something else to it rather than accepting it for what it is simply trying to tell you to do